# custom dimension with product and transaction hit

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, enhanced-ecommerce

I have some problems with using custom dimensions with enhanced ecoomerce. 
code below.

I would like to add 3 custom dimensions as product scopes and it works. but still I would like to add one custom dimension to transaction as hit scope. My below code doesn't works for dimension1. where should I place    'dimension1': 'zamowienie' to have info about the whole transaction, not olny products?

```
    dataLayer.push({
    'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': '194771', // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
        'dimension1': 'zamowienie',
        'revenue': '35.27',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping
        'shipping': '5.99'
      },
      'products': [{       
              'dimension2': 'JP Delaney',
                'dimension3': 'jak nowa',
                'dimension4': 'ksiazka',
        'name': 'Lokatorka',     // Name or ID is required.
        'id': '9788375150780',
        'price': '27.99',
        'quantity': 1                           // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
       },
       {
                 'dimension2': 'Kelly Creagh',
                'dimension3': 'widoczne ślady używania',
                'dimension4': 'ksiazka',
        'name': 'Nevermore T.1 Kruk',
        'id': '9788376860657',
        'price': '7.28',
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as you're using *product scopes* custom dimensions you need to put then alongside other product fields in the product object. In your example that would look like

```
{
    'dimension1': 'some value',
    'dimension2': 'JP Delaney',
    'dimension3': 'jak nowa',
    'dimension4': 'ksiazka',
    'name': 'Lokatorka',     // Name or ID is required.
    'id': '9788375150780',
    'price': '27.99',
    'quantity': 1  
},
```

however, this would make sense only to report persistent product properties otherwise your products wouldn't be aggregated properly in the reports. For example, having a product dimension value of 'zamowienie' in the transactions products but not in checkout products may result in missing that checkout steps in the funnel report with `dimensions1` since those would be treated as different products.